# How to create a view and update it later?

Tags: sql, database, syntax

Is it possible to update the same view with new data? Using `UPDATE` after `CREATE` didn't seem to work.

Have only 1 table. Want the view to be a subset of that table. After using the view, I would like the same view to hold a different subset of the data from the only table.

Was thinking I can create the view, drop it, then create it again with the same name ut different subset from the table.....but not sure if there is a better way?

```
Create view ID 1-10 if it does not exist.
. 
. //
. //
. 
Update view **ID** 2-10
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with `c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of a view.  What you are trying to do can be handled with a simple select by changing the WHERE clause. A view normally represents a fixed window into the table (or tables) defined by its selection criteria.  You wouldn't normally go changing the view dynamically to represent different selection criteria.  Normally, you'd simply do a select either against the table or against the view itself, if you're selecting a subset of the columns in the view or doing a join of multiple tables in the view.  Since you have a single table, I'd suggest just constructing the query you need dynamically and skipping the view entirely.

```
  select * from table where ID > 0 and ID <= 10
```

then

```
  select * from table where ID > 1 and ID <= 10
```

Note that in many cases you could save this as a stored procedure and parameterize the query if need be.  If your language/framework supports it, use parameterized queries when issuing simple commands as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, updates to base tables will be visible in a view (all other things being equal).
More information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Views are the wrong tool for this.

You should probably make a stored procedure that takes the ID range as a parameter.

To answer the question, you're looking for the [`ALTER VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx) statement.